# Categorizing defects to identify root cause

Tags: test-management

In my current project, we have a lot of defects :) arising from different areas of the system.

I would like to go to each defect and associate what is the root cause for that particular bug. Obviously, this is to understand the common areas a defect is coming from and to invest more where needed.

Do you have any suggestion what could be the lables that I should start with? Since there are about 500 defects, I do not want to make the process 
 and list very complicated.

I plan to start with:

- Requirement miss: out of scope.
- Requirement miss: unclear requirement
- Test miss: API
- Test miss: Functional
- Test miss: Non-functional
- Test miss: System
- Process: Release Management (Released without the test, released without documentation)

Howz this looking? Any other suggestion?

Comment: This is very opinion based question. there is no proper answer and more over the answer requires some knowledge of your system and your processes.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeyR., but would suggest you look at your definitions again - if a defect has been raised against API, Functional, Non-functional or System (which is probably the same as functional?), then how can it be defined as a 'Test Miss'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to get a list of root causes. And root causes vary on the basis of what we want to `accomplish` by doing RCA.  In my last company, our aim for root cause analysis was to find the origin of the bug (in which phase of SDLC was the defect introduced). So, here are some of the categories that we had:

1. Requirement Issue (ambiguous/missing/unclear requirement)
2. Design Issue
3. Coding Issue
4. Testing issue
5. Environment Issue
6. Deployment Issue
7. Out of scope (Something that was not part of requirements.)

**NOTE:** Getting `Testing Issues` is a tricky part as most of the stuff goes through testing. But, putting everything on testing squad will defeat the purpose. We also wanted to improve all the checkpoints that existed before the software is pushed to testers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to start with no list.

Since definition of defect category is quite different in each development, each context, also from each QA engineer. If we discuss about defect categories here we need another long discussion about definition of each ones.

Start right away with go-through session. When you discuss about root cause or area to improve for each defect, I believe you should come up with right category on your context specifically. It also allow your team to learn about each category together. Categories that come up from 500 defects should give you pretty good coverage category for your context.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the current technology paradigm, the application now a days are divided into followings areas:

1. Front End

   - UI Cosmetic
   - UI Design
   - UI Performance
   - UI Requirement Miss
2. Infrastructure

   - CI/CD Issue
   - Scaling Issue
   - Docker Container Issue
   - Performance Issue
3. Back End

   - API Functional Issue
   - API Authentication Issue
   - Performance Issue
   - API Requirement Miss
4. E2E

   - Test Coverage Issue
   - Validation Issue
   - Test Design Issue

The 500 defects can be categorized in the above so as to plan the release of artifacts in conjunction with priorities.